# Learn Ruby The Hard Way: Undefined method `close'

Tags: ruby, methods

This script is intended to take data from one file and copy it to another. I was challenged by Learn Ruby The Hard Way to write a one-liner, so:

```
from_file, to_file = ARGV
output = open(to_file, 'w').write(File.read(from_file))
output.close
```

I typed `ruby ex17.rb test.txt new_file.txt` in a terminal and get the error:

```
undefined method `close' for "new_file.txt":String (NoMethodError)
```

I cannot close any files using the script. If I keep all the methods `open`, `write`, and `read` separate, I have no problem closing things. I read that `File.read` automatically closes a file, but I'm only reading `from_file`. Wouldn't `to_file` still be open?

Some documentations use `File.open()`, but I haven't found it necessary, nor does *Learning Ruby The Hard Way* advise its use, to add `File.` to open a file. `open(filename)` seems to work on its own. But for `read`, it seems necessary to write `File.read`. Why the inconsistency with the usage?

Comment: Whether `File.read` automatically closes a file depends on whether you use it with a block.

Answer (score 0):

[`IO#write`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/IO.html#method-i-write) returns number of bytes written, hence, you cannot call `close` on it.

If you need single line solution, you can try

```
open(to_file, 'w') { |f| f.write (File.read(from_file)) }
```

`[IO#open][2]` will close the stream once the block is executed, no explicit `close` needed.
Similarly, [`IO#read`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/IO.html#method-i-read) closes the stream once file is fully read, no explicit `close` needed.